# Powershell: Get all User from OU who have empty Description Field and write EA6 tlo description

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have about 400 users in one OU. About 100 of these users have the Description field blank. The field Decription should now be filled with the value for the respective one in the attribute EA6. I want to use powershell for this. Can someone support here?
Thanks in advance.
Herman

These could be the first step. now the srcipt should get the EA1 to variable of all Users in $name and write this to the description of them.

$OUpath = 'OU=XX,OU=XXXX,OU=XXXXXXX,OU=Users,OU=XX,DC=XXX,DC=XXXXXXXXX,DC=XX'
$name = Get-AdUser -Filter {(Enabled -eq "True" ) -and (description -notlike '*')} -searchbase $OUpath -Properties Description | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SamAccountName

Comment: Welcome to SO. Did you take the [Tour] and did you read the help [Ask]? What kind of support do you need? Did you try to search for a solution? I'm sure there are hundrets of examples of how to acommplish such a task - even / especially here on SO.

Comment: You can limit the search for `Get-ADUser` by providing the `-SearchBase` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

To get the `extensionAttribute6` value from the user, you need to ask for it in the `-Properties` parameter for Get-ADUSer, just like the `Description` property, because both are not returned by default.

Then, you can do something like this:

```
$ou     = 'OU=Finance,OU=UserAccounts,DC=FABRIKAM,DC=COM'  # enter the distinguishedName of the OU here
$filter = "Enabled -eq $true -and Description -notlike '*'"

Get-AdUser -Filter $filter -SearchBase $ou -Properties Description, extensionAttribute6 | 
    ForEach-Object {
        $_ | Set-ADUser -Description $_.extensionAttribute6
    }
```

Comment: Hi theo,  thank you so much. changed only only one mistake $true to 'true'  Thats it.